Sequence empty only when checked from a certain command
I am trying to format song sheets in LaTeX. Within the lyrics (displayed on the left) are chords (defined with \note), which get highlighted and displayed on the right of the page. Choruses are outlined.
However, any chords within a Chorus block doesn't get added to the right column. I've previously tried an \fbox \parbox combination and got the same thing.
Ultimately the loop is:

Each time \note{} is called it checks if that chord already exists in \songchordlist. If it doesn't, the chord is added to both \songchordlist and \sectionchordlist. This is so that each chord is only displayed once on the right hand side.
At the end of each song section (\verse or \chorus), the \sectionchordlist is iterated over and notes placed on the right. This is so that when documents split pages, any notes that are on the second page but not the first are also shown on the second page. Once these chords have been added, \sectionchordlist is cleared.

I've added a load of debug messages in the console and it looks like \chorus IS successfully adding chords to \sectionchordlist, however when it comes to iterating through the list (only after being called by \chorus) \processchords shows a count of zero for it.
NOTE: Within \boxout, removing \begin{tcolorbox}#1\end{tcolorbox} and replacing with #1 works as intended. This was the behaviour I was seeing with an \fbox \parbox combo as well. All very odd!
Any ideas appreciated! MVP below and also available at overleaf.

%% =========CONFIGURATION VALUES===============================================================
\def \lyriccolumnwidth {400cm}              % Width of lyric column
\def \chordshapecolumnwidth {2cm}           % Width of chord shape column
\def \gapbetweenlyricsandshapes {200pt}     % Width between columns
\def \sectiongapsize {3mm}
\def \linespacing{1.2}
\def \boxoutwidth {\textwidth}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

%% =========PACKAGES===========================================================================
\setlength{\marginparsep}{1cm}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{paracol}
\setcolumnwidth{\lyriccolumnwidth, \chordshapecolumnwidth}
\setlength{\columnsep}{\gapbetweenlyricsandshapes}
\usepackage[]{tcolorbox}

%% =========CONFIGURATION AND COMMANDS=========================================================
\ExplSyntaxOn

% SONG CHORD LIST COMMANDS ===================================================

% Initialize the SONGS chord list as a sequence
\seq_new:N \songchordlist
\bool_new:N \chordexistsinsonglist
\bool_set_false:N \chordexistsinsonglist

\cs_new:Npn \check_in_songchordlist:n #1
  { 
  % Check if a chord is in songchordlist
  \debugwrite{Checking if #1 Is In SongChordList}
    \bool_set_false:N \chordexistsinsonglist
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \songchordlist
      {
        \str_if_eq:nnTF {##1} {#1}
          {
            \debugwrite{It IS In The List}
            \bool_set_true:N \chordexistsinsonglist 
          }
          {
            \debugwrite{It Is NOT In The List}
          }
      }
  }

\cs_new:Npn \add_to_songchordlist:n #1
{  
  \debugwrite{Adding #1 To SongChordList}
  \seq_put_right:Nn \songchordlist {#1}
}

\newcommand{\clearsongchordlist}{
  \debugwrite{Clearing Song Chord List}
  \bool_set_false:N \chordexistsinsonglist
  \seq_gclear:N \songchordlist 
}

% SECTION CHORD LIST COMMANDS ===================================================
% Initialize the SECTIONS chord list
\seq_new:N \sectionchordlist

\cs_new:Npn \add_to_sectionchordlist:n #1
{
  % Adds chord to sectionchordlist
  \debugwrite{Adding #1 To sectionchordlist}
  \seq_put_right:Nn \sectionchordlist {#1}
}

\newcommand{\clearsectionchordlist}{
  \debugwrite{Clearing sectionchordlist}
  \bool_set_false:N \chordexistsinsectionlist
  \seq_gclear:N \sectionchordlist 
}

% END OF SECTION CHORD LIST COMMANDS ===================================================

\newcommand{\validatechord}[1]{%
  % Checks if a chord already exists. If not, add it to the lists.
  \debugwrite{VALIDATECHORD #1}
  \check_in_songchordlist:n {#1}
  \bool_if:NTF \chordexistsinsonglist%
    {%
      % Do nothing if the chord exists
      \debugwrite{Chord #1 IS in SongList}
    }%
    {%
      % Add to the chord list if it doesn't exist
      \debugwrite{Chord #1 is NOT in SongList}
      \debugwrite{SongListLength - \seq_count:N{\songchordlist}}
      \debugwrite{SectionListLength - \seq_count:N{\sectionchordlist}}
      \add_to_songchordlist:n {#1}%
      \add_to_sectionchordlist:n {#1}%
    }%
}

\newcommand{\note}[1]{
    % Formats a chord/note within a lyric
  \debugwrite{--NOTE #1}
  \raisebox{0pt}{\textbf{[#1]}}
  % Check and update the chord list  
  \validatechord{#1}
}

\newcommand{\processchords}{
    % Goes through all found chords and 
    \debugwrite{PROCESS CHORDS - \seq_count:N{\sectionchordlist}}
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \sectionchordlist {
      \debugwrite{AddingShape##1}
      \addchordshape{##1} 
      }
    \seq_gclear:N \sectionchordlist
  }

\newcommand{\startnewsong}
{
  % Clears all flags ready for next song
  \debugwrite{-----------STARTING NEW SONG-------------}
  \newpage
  \clearsectionchordlist
  \clearsongchordlist
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\addchordshape}[1]{
    % Places chord shape in right column
    \switchcolumn
    #1
    \switchcolumn
}

\newcommand{\debugwrite}[1]{%
  \typeout{\protect#1}%
}

%% =========SONG FORMATTERS =========================================================
\newcommand{\boxout}[1]{
  % Outlines a section
  \debugwrite{Creating BoxOut}
  \tcbset{
    width=\boxoutwidth,
    halign=justify,
    center,
    colback=white    
    }

  \begin{tcolorbox}#1\end{tcolorbox} %<------- THIS IS THE PROB
  %#1 %<------------------- Uncomment this, comment line above, and it works
}

\newcommand{\songsection}[1]{%
  % Anything that needs to be done to every song section
  \debugwrite{SONG SECTION}
  \processchords
  \clearsectionchordlist
  \vspace{\sectiongapsize}
}

\newcommand{\chorus}[1]{%
  % Preformats CHORUS blocks
  \debugwrite{--CHORUS}%
  \boxout {%
    #1
  }%
  \songsection{#1}%
}

\renewcommand{\verse}[1]{%
  % Preformats VERSE blocks
  \debugwrite{--VERSE}%
  #1%
  \songsection{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\song}[3]{%
  % Preformats song details
  \debugwrite{--SONG}
  \startnewsong
  \begin{paracol}{2}
  \phantomsection% 
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1 - #2}
  \section*{\centering #1 - #2}\label{sec:#1#2}
  #3
  \end{paracol}
}

%% =========DOCUMENT===========================================================================
%%           DOCUMENT
%% ===========DOCUMENT=========================================================================
\debugwrite{--BUILDING DOCUMENT}

\begin{document}
    \obeyspaces
    \obeylines

    \song{Test Song}{VULGA}{
        \verse{

            \note{A}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            consectetur \note{B}adipiscing elit
            Integer pharetra pulvinar mi
            vitae \note{C}molestie ipsum
        }

        \chorus{
            \note{Ab}Maecenas vulputate hendrerit elementum
            Sed gravida \note{Bb}purus quis augue placerat fringilla
            Mauris eget sollicitudin sem, ac tincidunt arcu
            In tempor \note{Cb}viverra mi vel placerat
        }

        \verse{
            \note{D}Maecenas mattis nibh vel ultricies egestas
            Sed eget \note{E}mollis arcu
            Morbi \note{F}sollicitudin sagittis erat, ut lobortis ligula congue sit amet
            Interdum et malesuada \note{G}fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus
        }
    }
\end{document}


Welcome! Please can you reduce your code to a minimal working example i.e. enough code people can compile it to show the problem, but no more?

Please can you also update your expl3 to conform to the standard syntax? This is designed to make code clearer and reduce the chance of conflicts between packages i.e. to avoid the 2e mess ;). So e.g. \seq_new:N \songchordlist is wrong. It should be something like \seq_new:N \l__dansong_chordlist_seq where l indicates the variable is local and will only ever be set globally, the __ indicates it is internal (use _ for a public interface), dansong is the name of your module (hopefully unique), chordlist describes it and seq indicates the type.

Similarly all control sequences should start with \__dansong_... if internal or \dansong_... if public. And you should not mix local and global. \seq_put_right:Nn \songchordlist {#1} makes a local change which should mean an \l_ variable, but \seq_gclear:N \songchordlist  changes the variable globally, which should mean a \g_ variable. You should not use the same variable as both local and global. If you need both kinds, you need two variables. Incidentally or not, local/global confusion is probably relevant to your issue. A box means local, for example, as does and environment.

Thanks @cfr - as you can probably tell I'm new to LaTeX for this project but have a 'moderate' programming background.
I did alter the conventions but no change (I don't know if they ate just cosmetic or not). My assumption was that something to do with \begin{tcolorbox}#1\end{tcolorbox} is causing some kind of 'local-ness' but I'm not sure how or why that would happen. I'm fairly sure there is a basic level of understanding about LaTeX I'm missing which would explain it.

When I switch the stuff from local to global, I get the same content in the right column whether the tcolorbox line is uncommented or not. However, the labels are never stable regardless of which line is used. Is that what you see?

This gives the same right column with or without the tcolorbox. However, I'm not sure it is the intended behaviour. LaTeX complains the labels may have changed regardless of how many times it is compiled, with or without the tcolorbox. I'm also not sure what purpose all of the code is supposed to serve e.g. you have at least one undeclared boolean which is set in one place but appears to serve no function.
Note that all I've done is tidy up the expl3 syntax and treat the variables consistently as global.
On recent kernels, you don't need to load xparse or expl3. Note also that hyperref likes to be loaded late with certain exceptions.
I'm not sure what purpose the \defs before \documentclass serve or why you haven't used dimensions, lengths or skips here. Note that expl3 has support for both dimensions and skips, but if you need core TeX for some reason, setting or creating them as dimension registers would seem more natural. (Obviously, this doesn't apply to e.g. \linespacing which isn't a dimension and anyway already exists.)
\def \lyriccolumnwidth {400cm}              % Width of lyric column
\def \chordshapecolumnwidth {2cm}           % Width of chord shape column
\def \gapbetweenlyricsandshapes {200pt}     % Width between columns
\def \sectiongapsize {3mm}
\def \linespacing{1.2}
\def \boxoutwidth {\textwidth}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\setlength{\marginparsep}{1cm}
% the point of parskip is to set \parskip non-zero!
% \setlength{\parindent}{0pt} would kill indentation
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{paracol}
\setcolumnwidth{\lyriccolumnwidth, \chordshapecolumnwidth}
\setlength{\columnsep}{\gapbetweenlyricsandshapes}
\usepackage[]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Initialize the SONGS chord list as a sequence
\seq_new:N \g_dansong_chordlist_seq
\seq_new:N \g_dansong_sectionchordlist_seq
\bool_new:N \g_dansong_chordexistsinsonglist_bool
\bool_gset_false:N \g_dansong_chordexistsinsonglist_bool
\bool_new:N \g_dansong_chordexistsinsectionlist_seq % what is this for?

\cs_new:Npn \dansong_check_in_songchordlist:n #1
{ 
  % Check if a chord is in songchordlist
  \debugwrite{Checking if #1 Is In SongChordList}
  \bool_gset_false:N \g_dansong_chordexistsinsonglist_bool
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_dansong_chordlist_seq
  {
    \str_if_eq:nnTF {##1} {#1}
    {
      \debugwrite{It IS In The List}
      \bool_gset_true:N \g_dansong_chordexistsinsonglist_bool 
    }
    {
      \debugwrite{It Is NOT In The List}
    }
  }
}

\cs_new:Npn \dansong_add_to_songchordlist:n #1
{  
  \debugwrite{Adding #1 To SongChordList}
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_dansong_chordlist_seq {#1}
}

\newcommand{\clearsongchordlist}{
  \debugwrite{Clearing Song Chord List}
  \bool_gset_false:N \g_dansong_chordexistsinsonglist_bool
  \seq_gclear:N \g_dansong_chordlist_seq 
}

% SECTION CHORD LIST COMMANDS ===================================================
% Initialize the SECTIONS chord list

\cs_new:Npn \dansong_gadd_to_sectionchordlist:n #1
{
  % Adds chord to sectionchordlist
  \debugwrite{Adding #1 To sectionchordlist}
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_dansong_sectionchordlist_seq {#1}
}

\newcommand{\clearsectionchordlist}{
  \debugwrite{Clearing sectionchordlist}
  \bool_gset_false:N \g_dansong_chordexistsinsectionlist_seq % purpose?
  \seq_gclear:N \g_dansong_sectionchordlist_seq 
}

% END OF SECTION CHORD LIST COMMANDS ===================================================

\newcommand{\validatechord}[1]{%
  % Checks if a chord already exists. If not, add it to the lists.
  \debugwrite{VALIDATECHORD #1}
  \dansong_check_in_songchordlist:n {#1}
  \bool_if:NTF \g_dansong_chordexistsinsonglist_bool
  {%
    % Do nothing if the chord exists
    \debugwrite{Chord #1 IS in SongList}
  }%
  {%
    % Add to the chord list if it doesn't exist
    \debugwrite{Chord #1 is NOT in SongList}
    \debugwrite{SongListLength - \seq_count:N{\g_dansong_chordlist_seq}}
    \debugwrite{SectionListLength - \seq_count:N{\g_dansong_sectionchordlist_seq}}
    \dansong_add_to_songchordlist:n {#1}%
    \dansong_gadd_to_sectionchordlist:n {#1}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\note}[1]{
  % Formats a chord/note within a lyric
  \debugwrite{--NOTE #1}
  \raisebox{0pt}{\textbf{[#1]}}
  % Check and update the chord list  
  \validatechord{#1}
}

\newcommand{\processchords}{
  % Goes through all found chords and 
  \debugwrite{PROCESS CHORDS - \seq_count:N{\g_dansong_sectionchordlist_seq}}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_dansong_sectionchordlist_seq {
    \debugwrite{AddingShape##1}
    \addchordshape{##1} 
  }
  \seq_gclear:N \g_dansong_sectionchordlist_seq
}

\newcommand{\startnewsong}
{
  % Clears all flags ready for next song
  \debugwrite{-----------STARTING NEW SONG-------------}
  \newpage
  \clearsectionchordlist
  \clearsongchordlist
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\addchordshape}[1]{% an uncommented line ending is a space
  % Places chord shape in right column
  \switchcolumn
  #1
  \switchcolumn
}

\newcommand{\debugwrite}[1]{%
  \typeout{\protect#1}%
}

%% =========SONG FORMATTERS =========================================================
\newcommand{\boxout}[1]{%
  % Outlines a section
  \debugwrite{Creating BoxOut}
  \tcbset{
    width=\boxoutwidth,
    halign=justify,
    center,
    colback=white    
  }
  
  \begin{tcolorbox}#1\end{tcolorbox} %<------- THIS IS THE PROB
  %#1 %<------------------- Uncomment this, comment line above, and it works
}

\newcommand{\songsection}[1]{%
  % Anything that needs to be done to every song section
  \debugwrite{SONG SECTION}%
  \processchords
  \clearsectionchordlist
  \vspace{\sectiongapsize}
}

\newcommand{\chorus}[1]{%
  % Preformats CHORUS blocks
  \debugwrite{--CHORUS}%
  \boxout {%
    #1
  }%
  \songsection{#1}%
}

\renewcommand{\verse}[1]{%
  % Preformats VERSE blocks
  \debugwrite{--VERSE}%
  #1%
  \songsection{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\song}[3]{%
  % Preformats song details
  \debugwrite{--SONG}%
  \startnewsong
  \begin{paracol}{2}
    \phantomsection% 
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1 - #2}%
    % \centering does nothing unless there's a paragraph break in #1 or #2
    \section*{\centering #1 - #2}\label{sec:#1#2}
    #3
  \end{paracol}%
}

\debugwrite{--BUILDING DOCUMENT}

\begin{document}
\obeyspaces
\obeylines

\song{Test Song}{VULGA}{
  \verse{
    
    \note{A}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    consectetur \note{B}adipiscing elit
    Integer pharetra pulvinar mi
    vitae \note{C}molestie ipsum
  }
  
  \chorus{
    \note{Ab}Maecenas vulputate hendrerit elementum
    Sed gravida \note{Bb}purus quis augue placerat fringilla
    Mauris eget sollicitudin sem, ac tincidunt arcu
    In tempor \note{Cb}viverra mi vel placerat
  }
  
  \verse{
    \note{D}Maecenas mattis nibh vel ultricies egestas
    Sed eget \note{E}mollis arcu
    Morbi \note{F}sollicitudin sagittis erat, ut lobortis ligula congue sit amet
    Interdum et malesuada \note{G}fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus
  }
}
\end{document}


Thank you so much - going through your code it was the change to \seq_gput_right which immediately fixed the issue.
Thank you very much for your efforts with this!

@danabnormal Some of what I changed won't cause problems unless you turn on a higher level of checking, but they may cause issues later on and make the code less readable. E.g. I initially thought it would be easy to see if the problem lay in your setting a variable only locally precisely because you were using expl3. Because I expected the variable name to immediately tell me whether it was local or global. But you weren't using that scheme and used the same variable both locally and globally, so the situation was much more muddled. The syntax make it much easier to predict effects & debug.

@danabnormal You should be careful with \def especially with names which are really quite likely to cause conflicts e.g. \boxoutwidth. That sounds very much like a name which might end up conflicting with something else that gets loaded. I don't really know why you don't just use \textwidth? If this is meant to be a user interface, it is not a good way to do it. A key-value interface in the document preamble would be better. And setting proper dimensions and so on. For line spacing, take a look at setspace.sty, but you might not want it for something this specialised. Etc.
